# C#: построение дерево объектов выгруженных в память объектов

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Добрый день.

Сегодня загорелся таким вопросом: если приложение (например win-сервис) используется в своей работе какие-то экземпляры классов, то значит они где-то хранятся, а значит можно получить их перечень.

Можно ли как-то с помощью C# узнать, какие объекты выгружены в память, в каком кол-ве, владельцем которых есть конкретный виндовс-сервис?
Это я планирую сделать нечто вроде профайлера.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте компонент [CLR Memory Diagnostics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime) (ClrMD):

```
int pid = Process.GetProcessesByName("HelloWorld")[0].Id;
using (DataTarget dataTarget = DataTarget.AttachToProcess(pid, 5000))
{
    string dacLocation = dataTarget.ClrVersions[0].TryGetDacLocation();
    ClrRuntime runtime = dataTarget.CreateRuntime(dacLocation);

    ClrHeap heap = runtime.GetHeap();
    foreach (ulong obj in heap.EnumerateObjects())
    {
        ClrType type = heap.GetObjectType(obj);
        ulong size = type.GetSize(obj);
        Console.WriteLine("{0,12:X} {1,8:n0} {2}", obj, size, type.Name);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

> ```
>      23B1D30       36 System.Security.PermissionSet
>      23B1D54       20 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePEFileHandle
>      23B1D68       32 System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory
>      23B1D88       40 System.Security.Policy.Evidence
> ```

Более подробно можно почитать в статье [.NET Crash Dump and Live Process Inspection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection/). Конкретные сценарии работы с ClrMD можно найти [в официальном репозитории](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnetsamples/tree/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime/CLRMD). Плюс стоит обратить внимание на [ClrMD.Extensions](https://github.com/JeffCyr/ClrMD.Extensions), которая несколько облегчает работу с ClrMD.

С помощью этого компонента можно также анализировать файлы дампа.

---

В случае, если вы умеете работать с unmanaged кодом, более правильно будет воспользоваться [Profiling API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386(v=VS.100).aspx).